# django getting the absolute path of a FileField

Tags: django, url-rewriting, django-urls

I am trying to retrieve the absolute path (starting with http://) while calling a FileField at the template.

How can I achieve this ?

ie:
`{{fl.uploadedfile}}` -> returns relative path like media/uploads/
while I want [This](http://www.blabla.com/media/uploads/)

Cheers

Answer (score 15):

The [Django File object](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/files/file/) provides several convenience functions/attributes, one of which is the URL associated with the file. In this case, as you pointed out, you're looking for the `url` attribute.

Comment: it seems that in the mentioned link there is no reference to an `url` attribute. Did you meant referring to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#filefield ?

Answer (score 10):

Just found the answer:
adding .url fixes this issue fixes it
such as `{{fl.uploadedfile.url}}`